# Navigate to tab that contains Lightning Web Component with record Id as parameter

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am able to navigate to visualforce using record id as parameter. But I am not able to do this in LWC. I will give the illustration of what I want to achieve.

In the `Onboarding List` page that also visualforce page there is table element contain all the record in the `Onboarding` object and we able to call the visualforce from the table using this:

OnboardingList.vfp:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <apex:repeat id="repeatOnboarding" var="dt" value="{!onboardingList}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputLink value="{!$Site.prefix}/apex/OnboardingDetailPage?oid={!dt.Id}&action=detail">{!dt.Name}</apex:outputLink>
            </td>
            <td>{!dt.Email}</td>
            <td>{!dt.Phone}</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
```

and `Onboarding Detail` page will be the page (also visualforce page) that show the customized detail of the record, this detail page we customize is very complex that require consolidating all the data related to that record.

In `Onboarding Detail` controller, I am able to get the Id of the record using this:

OnboardingDetail.cls:

```
public OnboardingDetail() {
    String oId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oid');
    String action = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('action');
}
```

So, back to LWC, this is the `Onboarding List` page that I've created and I am able to get the Id of the record using this:

OnboardingList.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Onboarding" icon-name="action:new_task">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={onboardingList.data}>
                <table id="tblOnboardingList">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <template for:each={onboardingList.data} for:item="dt" for:index="indexvar">
                            <tr id="datarow">
                                <td>
                                    <!-- call js function and carry the iterated record id -->
                                    <a onclick={navigateToOnboardingDetail} data-id={dt.id}>
                                        {!dt.Account.Name}
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{!dt.Email}</td>
                                <td>{!dt.Phone}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </template>
            <template if:true={onboardingList.error}>
                {onboardingList.error}
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

In the js file, the `event.target.dataset.id` will contains the record Id

OnboardingList.js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

import getBacklog from '@salesforce/apex/OnboardingHandler.getOnboardingBacklog';

export default class OnboardingPage extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(getBacklog) onboardingList;

    navigateToOnboardingDetail(event) {
        console.log('get the record id: ' + event.target.dataset.id);
        event.preventDefault();
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                //how to apply this id and navigate to tab that has LWC component?
                //recordId: event.target.dataset.id,
                apiName: 'Onboarding_Detail'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How to navigate to the **tab** that contains LWC and carry the record Id due to the `standard__navItemPage` doesn't support `recordId` as attributes

Is there any workaround to do this if the standard NavigationMixin is not possible? How can I achieve this in LWC?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly the solution you are looking for, but it's a work-around that I've been using.

I pass the recordId as a URL parameter to the tab. (Note, I use `window.open(THEURL, '_top')` instead of NavigationMixin because that did not refresh the tab and reload the contents with the newly passed parameters)

I generate the THEURL of page similar to this:
`/lightning/n/TABNAME?c__recordId=XXX`

In the receiving LWC, I have an edit form with an "onload" handler:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} onload={handleLoad}>
```

In the handleLoad, I have this code to pull the parameter in and set the recordId:

```
handleLoad() {
    if ( this.pageRef && this.pageRef.state['c__recordId'] ) {
        this.recordId = this.pageRef.state['c__recordId'];
    }
}//handleLoad
```

*(These are code excerpts... but give the overall concept that I've been using.  This has been working for me; and it works whether the LWC is embedded on a record layout, or shown as its own tab with the parameter.)*

Comment: can you explain how are you generating this URL - /lightning/n/TABNAME?c__recordId=XXX

Comment: I have a similar requirement and opening a record page and want to read the parameters in my LWC component present on the URL before they get vanished

Comment: Parameters that begin with c__ are not stripped and can be retrieved by the LWC component using this.pageRef.state[]

Comment: Wonderful! This solves the problem.

Comment: @PaulN can you help me with pageRef, from where you are getting this? I am trying to get the recordId passed from LWC component.

Comment: @RKM - I pass the parameter "c__recordId" manually via URL when I create the link to the page containing the LWC.  Then you can use "this.pageRef" to retrieve the parameters within the LWC javascript